# Finding the distance between the two closest elements in an array of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

So I'm teaching myself algorithms from this book I purchased, and I have a pseudo-code for Finding the distance between the two closetst elements in an array of numbers

```
MinDistance(a[0...n-1])
Input: Array A of numbers
Output: Minimum Distance between two of its elements
dMin <- maximum integer

for i=0 to n-1 do
   for j=0 to n-1 do
      if i!=j and | A[i] - A[j] | < dMin
        dMin = | A[i]-A[j] |
return dMin
```

However, I wanted to make improvements to this algorithmic solution. Change what's already there, or rewrite all together. Can someone help?
I wrote the function and class in Java to test the pseudo-code? Is that correct? And once again, how can I make it better from efficiency standpoint.

```
//Scanner library allowing the user to input data
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class ArrayTester{
    //algorithm for finding the distance between the two closest elements in an array of numbers
    public int MinDistance(int [] ar){
    int [] a = ar;
    int aSize = a.length;
    int dMin = 0;//MaxInt
    for(int i=0; i< aSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j< aSize;j++)
        {   
            dMin = Math.min(dMin, Math.abs( a[i]-a[j] );
        }
    }
    return dMin;
}

    //MAIN
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayTester at = new ArrayTester();
        int [] someArray = {9,1,2,3,16};
        System.out.println("NOT-OPTIMIZED METHOD");
        System.out.println("Array length = "+ someArray.length);
        System.out.println("The distance between the two closest elements: " + at.MinDistance(someArray));

    } //end MAIN

} //END CLASS
```

SO I updated the function to minimize calling the Math.abs twice. What else can I do improve it. If I was to rewrite it with sort, would it change my for loops at all, or would it be the same just theoretically run faster.

```
public int MinDistance(int [] ar){
        int [] a = ar;
        int aSize = a.length;
        int dMin = 0;//MaxInt
        for(int i=0; i< aSize; i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1; j< aSize;j++)
            {   
                dMin = Math.min(dMin, Math.abs( a[i]-a[j] );
            }
        }
        return dMin;
    }
```

Comment: You initialize dMin to 0, and comment it with "//MaxInt". You can get the maximum integer in java with "Integer.MAX_VALUE".

Answer (score 12):

One obvious efficiency improvement: sort the integers first, then you can look at adjacent ones. Any number is going to be closest to its neighbour either up or down.

That changes the complexity from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n log n). Admittedly for the small value of `n` shown it's not going to make a significant difference, but in terms of theoretical complexity it's important.

One micro-optimization you may want to make: use a local variable to store the result of `Math.abs`, then you won't need to recompute it if that turns out to be less than the minimum. Alternatively, you might want to use `dMin = Math.min(dMin, Math.abs(a[i] - a[j]))`.

Note that you need to be careful of border conditions - if you're permitting negative numbers, your subtraction might overflow.

Comment: Since he's sorting integers, he can further use an O(n) sorting algorithm like Radix Sort.

Comment: how can you find the distance between closest elements in array when you sort the array? If we are sorting ,all we can find is which two elements are closest to each other .

Comment: @Barry: Well the closest neighbour to item index `i` is either going to be at index `i + 1` or index `i - 1` - so you can find *that* closest distance easily. Then just iterate over the array to find the smallest "closest distance" if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

That's a naive solution of O(n^2).

Better way:

Sort the array, then go over it once more and check the distance between the sorted items.
This will work because they are in ascending order, so the number with the nearest value is adjacent.

That solution will be O(nlogn)

Comment: sort it with the library sort?

Comment: The library sort is probably well implemented

Answer (score 2):

First of all, before making it fast, make it correct. Why is `dmin` initialized with the length of the array? If the array is `[1, 1000]`, the result of your algorithm will be 2 instead of 999.

Then, why do you make j go from 0 to the length of the array? You compare each pair of elements twice. You should make j go from i + 1 to the length of the array (which will also avoid the i != j comparison).

Finally, you could gain a few nanoseconds by avoiding calling Math.abs() twice.

And then, you could completely change your algorithm by sorting the array first, as noted in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can theoretically get an O(n) solution by

1. sorting with <strike>shell</strike> radix sort  *(edited, thanks to j_random_hacker for pointing it out)*
2. one pass to find difference between numbers

Comment: Shell sort is not O(n).  According to Wikipedia, the best bound varies according to the gap sequence chosen, but is always worse than O(nlog n).  Maybe you're thinking of bucket sort?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, +1 for pointing out. Fixed my answer. user628796 can use radix sort, as the problem space is all numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a question:

How long would it take to find the min distance if the array was sorted?

You should be able to finish the rest out from here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the array first would exempt us from using another FOR loop.

```
    public static int distclosest(int numbers[]) {
       Arrays.sort(numbers);
       int aSize = numbers.length;
       int dMin = numbers[aSize-1];

       for(int i=0; i<aSize-1; i++) {
                dMin = Math.min(dMin, numbers[i+1]-numbers[i]);
       }
       return dMin;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  static void MinNumber(int [] nums){

    Arrays.sort(nums);
    int min = nums[1] - nums[0]; 
    int indexOne = 0 , indexTwo = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length -1; i++) {
        if (min > (nums[i+1] - nums[i])) {
            min = nums[i+1] - nums[i] ; 
            indexOne = i ; 
            indexTwo = i+1 ; 
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Minimum number between two values is: "+ min + " and the values is "+nums[indexOne]+" , "+nums[indexTwo] );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

np: sorting the array is a must before executing the algorithm.

```
static int minDist(int arr[]) {
    int firstPointer, nextPointer;
    int minDistance = arr[1] - arr[0];
    int tempDistance;

    for (firstPointer = 0; firstPointer < arr.length; firstPointer++) {
        for (nextPointer = firstPointer + 1; nextPointer < arr.length; nextPointer++) {
            if (arr[nextPointer] == arr[firstPointer]) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                tempDistance = (arr[nextPointer] - arr[firstPointer]);
                if (minDistance > tempDistance) {
                    minDistance = tempDistance;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return minDistance;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] testArray = {1000, 1007, 3, 9, 21};
    Arrays.sort(testArray);
    int result = minDist(testArray);
    System.out.println(result); 
}
```