# Cannot implicitly convert type int to int[]

Tags: c#

I don't know why I've come up with the following CS0029 error in the last line (return dmin).  It's telling me that I can't implicitly convert type int to int[]:

```
private static int[] MinDistance(int[] sortedArray)
    {
        int dmin = int.MaxValue;

        int length = sortedArray.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < length - 1 - i; j++)
            {

                if (sortedArray[i] != sortedArray[j] && Math.Abs(i - j) < dmin) 
                {

                    dmin = Math.Abs(i - j);

                }
            }
        }
        return dmin;
```

Comment: Yes, because your method is declared to return an `int[]` - did you mean to do that?

Comment: `Math.Abs(i - j)` or `Math.Abs(sortedArray[i] - sortedArray[j])` ?

Comment: you logic is wrong, tell us what you are hoping to achieve and we can suggest the correct way to fix it

Comment: Based on your posted answer below it's very confusing what you're actually trying to achieve. Your method signature in the question suggests you are passing a sorted array of ints into the method. The answer you posted below suggests you are passing an unsorted array of ints and trying to return a sorted array from MinDistance. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Jon - I've got a line of numbers (array) which I need to return to calculate the minimum distance between the two closest elements

Comment: I'm looking to calculate the minimum distance between the two closest elements in an array

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082756/finding-the-distance-between-the-two-closest-elements-in-an-array-of-numbers this should give you an idea, actually it pretty much answers your question, so no point in me writing it

Answer (score 1):

dmin is an Int, but MinDistance is returning an array of int (int[]). If you need the int and not an array change the first line to:

```
private static int MinDistance(int[] sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
private static int MinDistance(int[] sortedArray)
    {
        int dmin = int.MaxValue;

    int length = sortedArray.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < length - 1 - i; j++)
        {

            if (sortedArray[i] != sortedArray[j] && Math.Abs(i - j) < dmin) 
            {

                dmin = Math.Abs(i - j);

            }
        }
    }
    return dmin;
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said, your mistake is here to declare your function as returning an Array of int (> int[]) where as in the code, you are returning an int value (dmin, the minimum value of your to-be-sorted array).

What you need to do is :

1/ change the declaration of your function so it returns an int, as stated by Aimnox

2/ declare an int where you are calling your function :

```
int[] sortedArray = MinDistance(unsortedArray); // WRONG
int minValue = MinDistance(unsortedArray); // RIGHT
```

Answer (score 0):

you've gotten yourself tied in knots here with your arrays

you are feeding in an array converting it to an integer value and then trying to treat that as an array, so firstly you need to think about what you are doing

so do you want THE minumum value or ALL minimum values?

if its THE min then

```
int min = MinDistance(array);
private static int MinDistance(int[] sortedArray)
{
    int dmin = int.MaxValue;

    int length = sortedArray.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < length - 1 - i; j++)
        {

            if (sortedArray[i] != sortedArray[j] && Math.Abs(i - j) < dmin) 
            {

                dmin = Math.Abs(i - j);

            }
        }
    }
    return dmin;
}
```

if its ALL then

```
int[] allMin = MinDistance(array);
private static int[] MinDistance(int[] sortedArray)
{
    List<int> dmin = new List<int>();

    int length = sortedArray.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < length - 1 - i; j++)
        {

            if (sortedArray[i] != sortedArray[j] && Math.Abs(i - j) < dmin) 
            {

                dmin.Add(Math.Abs(i - j));

            }
        }
    }
    return dmin.ToArray();
}
```

note this just corrects the typing issue not your logic